# Styling an image based on its current position

Tags: html, css

I have a rectangle image and on click of it I need to add a small circle at it's lower right corner. Please have a look at the codepen [example.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpvGaO)

The position of the image keeps changing based on some conditions set. 
As soon as the image's position changes, I would need the dot also to move accordingly.

I don't want to keep updating the `left` and `top` positions for the dot whenever the image position changes.

(Note: Please don't worry about the `.box1` and `.box2` css. The actual code has  an image.)

All I need is to make sure the dot gets aligned with the current position of the image. Please advise if it is possible through css tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When positioning an element in CSS with `position: absolute` it will reference the closest parent with the position value `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`. Update the `position` for parent container where the red dot is in, in case of your example `.box1` and `.box2`.

Since you want the red dot in the bottom right of the container use the `right` and `bottom` properties instead `left` and `top`.

Below is your example with suggested edits:

```css
.box1    {  
  width:65px;
  height:40px;
  /* Added position */
  position: relative; 
  box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.45);
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
  border-right:2px solid #fff;
}

.box2 {
  width:65px;
  height:40px;
  box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.45);
  position: absolute;
  left:100px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 5px;
}

.image-active {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  /* replace left & top properties */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="image-active"></div>
</div>  
  
<div class="box2">
  <div class="image-active"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg!  How could I not think about position:relative on the parent elem.  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct about you question. This is the output that you are trying to achieve. In here I used float to position both div to the left. Then declare the box1 and box2 into "position: relative" so that I can able to control both image inside of it while applying the css style "position: absolute"

```css
.box1    {  
  width:65px;
  height:40px;
  box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.45);
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
  border-right:2px solid #fff;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.box2 {
  width:65px;
  height:40px;
  box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.45);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.image-active {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70%;
  top: 42%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="image-active"></div>
</div>  
  
<div class="box2">
  <div class="image-active"></div>
</div>
```